# Custom Simple Type Model Binder not working for string trimming

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

I am trying to implement string trimming model binder in .net core 2.1. What I have done is I have created a Custom Model Binder, created a provider for that and have registered it in the startup class.

My expectation is if any model has a string property it will trim the value and set in the model binder. I am only targeting strings, so I have made a check in the provider that only return the binder if the model type is a string.

But the model binders BindModelAsync method never gets called although.

Am I missing some important piece of code ?? Any help would be really appreciated.

**TrimmingModelBinder**

```
public class TrimmingModelBinder  : IModelBinder
   {
        private readonly IModelBinder FallbackBinder;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fallbackBinder"></param>        
    public TrimmingModelBinder(IModelBinder fallbackBinder)
    {
        FallbackBinder = fallbackBinder ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fallbackBinder));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bindingContext"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (valueProviderResult != null &&
          valueProviderResult.FirstValue is string str &&
          !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(str.Trim());
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        return FallbackBinder.BindModelAsync(bindingContext);
    }
}
```

**TrimmingModelBinderProvider**

```
  public class TrimmingModelBinderProvider  : IModelBinderProvider
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"> context </param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
        {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }
        if (!context.Metadata.IsComplexType && context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(string))
        {
            var loggerFactory = context.Services.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
            return new TrimmingModelBinder(new SimpleTypeModelBinder(context.Metadata.ModelType, loggerFactory));
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
services
            .AddMvcCore()
            .AddMvcOptions(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add<ServiceClientExceptionFilter>();
                var simpleTypeModelBinderProvider = options.ModelBinderProviders.First(x => x.GetType() == typeof(SimpleTypeModelBinderProvider));
                var index = options.ModelBinderProviders.IndexOf(simpleTypeModelBinderProvider);
                options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new TrimmingModelBinderProvider());
            })
```

Comment: "My expectation is if any model has a string property it will trim the value and set in the model binder" : Are you sending the payload as a json? if so, the code won't work because it is processed by formatter

Comment: For Json format, you could create a custom JsonConverter to achieve that goal.

Comment: @itminus Question is why the model binder not working, I know the alternatives.

Comment: If you're sending a json payload. The code won't work. because it is processed by input formatter.

Comment: @itminus  is model binder is not used for binding the json content?

Comment: No. By default, ASP.NET Core will use JSON Converter to deserialize the Request Body, and then bind it to a parameter. But if there's a model binder related attribute decorated, you could use a custom binder. As your `TrimmingModelBinderProvider` will only provide the binder for string types, it won't take effects at all.